# Download page for Ubuntu leads to unsecure http link

Tags: downloads, https

I needed to redownload ubuntu and the official site https://ubuntu.com/download/desktop leads to an unsecure http link http://ftp.antik.sk/ubuntu-releases/19.10/ubuntu-19.10-desktop-amd64.iso

Is that a security threat or can I trust this link? Is there an alternative safe way to download ubuntu?

Comment: You don't need a "safe" link. Just check a MD5 sum of the iso, if you are paranoid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to verify that the .iso has not been tampered with, you can [check its md5](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM) or sha1 checksum. Then it doesn't matter where you download it from.

Comment: https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu#0 is another good procedure from the publishers of Ubuntu.

Comment: Thank you for the answer :)